# Implement objective fuction such that element that will be maximised with specific patern (x1+x2)/5 +(x1+x2)/ 2 + (y1+y2)/4 so on

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have created a objective function using pulp but I am not able to implement the specific pattern

```
prob = LpProblem("Delivery_Problem",LpMaximize)
items_names = df_items['name'].tolist()
print(items_names)

['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9', 'n10']

lp_trucks_items = [LpVariable.dicts("Truck {}".format(truck_number), items_names, lowBound=0, cat='Integer') 
                   for truck_number in range(len(trucks_possible_loads))]



 [{'n1': Truck_0_n1,
      'n2': Truck_0_n2,
      'n3': Truck_0_n3,
      
      
      'n10': Truck_0_n10},
     {'n1': Truck_1_n1,
      'n2': Truck_1_n2,
      'n3': Truck_1_n3, and so on
```

Now I have an array with weight and vol such truck 1 [2000,30] truck 2 [3000, 100]

When I execute

```
prob += lpSum([
    lp_truck_items[item['name']]
    for _,item in df_items.iterrows() 
    for lp_truck_items in lp_trucks_items
])
```

I get output maximise

```
1*Truck_0_n1 + 1*Truck_0_n10 + 1*Truck_0_n2 + 1*Truck_0_n3 + 1*Truck_0_n4 + 1*Truck_0_n5 + 1*Truck_0_n6 + 1*Truck_0_n7 + 1*Truck_0_n8 + 1*Truck_0_n9 + 1*Truck_1_n1 + 1*Truck_1_n10 + 1*Truck_1_n2 + 1*Truck_1_n3 + 1*Truck_1_n4 + 1*Truck_1_n5 + 1*Truck_1_n6 + 1*Truck_1_n7 + 1*Truck_1_n8 + 1*Truck_1_n9 + 0
```

What I need is maximise

```
(1*Truck_0_n1 + 1*Truck_0_n10 + 1*Truck_0_n2 + 1*Truck_0_n3 + 1*Truck_0_n4 + 1*Truck_0_n5 + 1*Truck_0_n6 + 1*Truck_0_n7 + 1*Truck_0_n8 + 1*Truck_0_n9) / 2000 + (1*Truck_0_n1 + 1*Truck_0_n10 + 1*Truck_0_n2 + 1*Truck_0_n3 + 1*Truck_0_n4 + 1*Truck_0_n5 + 1*Truck_0_n6 + 1*Truck_0_n7 + 1*Truck_0_n8 + 1*Truck_0_n9) / 30 +  (1*Truck_1_n1 + 1*Truck_1_n10 + 1*Truck_1_n2 + 1*Truck_1_n3 + 1*Truck_1_n4 + 1*Truck_1_n5 + 1*Truck_1_n6 + 1*Truck_1_n7 + 1*Truck_1_n8 + 1*Truck_1_n9)/ 3000 + (1*Truck_1_n1 + 1*Truck_1_n10 + 1*Truck_1_n2 + 1*Truck_1_n3 + 1*Truck_1_n4 + 1*Truck_1_n5 + 1*Truck_1_n6 + 1*Truck_1_n7 + 1*Truck_1_n8 + 1*Truck_1_n9)/ 100 + 0
```

I tried multiple ways to loop but not getting the pattern

How can I build the needed objective function?

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions you show are equivalent. Maximizing "A" is equivalent to maximizing "100 x A" or "A / 100". As long as you multiply the whole expression with a constant (in your case 1/100),  you will always obtain the same optimal solution.